# Failed to extract an attribute using beautifulsoup in deep div tree

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract an attribute from a deep `<div>` tree. I tried `find_all` and select; both failed. Please help. The line in grey is what I need. I need to get the value of `data-num` out which is 2.

Basically, I need to get the value orange on the top right of https://www.xin.com/c2b_car_o/201/

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Please tell us, how exactly you used `find_all` and `select`.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: In order to be able to receive help from people, you should provide more information. In this case you should provide the code that you already tried without success. Please, take a look on the next post in order to improve [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. I finally found a solution.

[problem]: I could not locate the web elements using beautifulsoup. 
[reason]: the element was rendered by javascript. I don't know why? but that's the answer I got from another source. I was told that I need to use selenium. 
[solution]: I used selemium to successfully extracted the numbers. See my code below. 
[more help]: the problem is solved! But I am unclear what situation is good for selenium. And how do I know what a specific element is rendered by javascript which can't be extracted using beautifulsoup. Please give a try and post your code if you can do it using bs4. Or, please provide more explanations.  Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('G:\chromedriver\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.xin.com/c2b_car_o/201/")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="mt-number-animate-dom"]')
num_str=[el.get_attribute("data-num") for el in elements]
print(int(''.join(num_str)))
```

Comment: elements=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mt-number-animate-dom"})  # beautifulsoup could not locate the element